# Are these two links equivalent?

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, kirby-diagram

> Are the following two links equivalent (orientation preserving isotopies)?[image]

The two links have the same linking number. The only difference is the crossing that in one case is positive while in the other negative. In other words, the writhe of the curled component is different (but the writhe is not  invariant under the first Reidemeister move).

The most naive approach would be to rotate part of the picture but these kind of transformations cannot change the writhe.

Motivation:
This kind of pictures pop up in studying  Kirby diagrams of  $\mathbb{D}^2$ bundles over $\mathbb{RP}^2$. In particular I expect them to be equivalent.

Comment: Have you tried computing their Jones polynomials or similar?

Comment: I made a model of the link on the right out of paper and have been trying to manipulate it into the one on the left. No luck so far!

Comment: I don't trust my computations yet but I think the Jones polynomials are different.

Comment: They are mirror images of each other.  The Jones polynomials depend a bit on orientations of components (due to writhe), but ignoring that both are, up to mirror image, L4a1 in the LinkInfo tables (a.k.a. the $T(2,4)$ and $T(2,-4)$ torus links).  I computed the Jones polynomials with https://kmill.github.io/knotfolio/ by pasting in the image of the diagrams.  The Jones polynomials are related by $t \mapsto t^{-1}$.

Comment: While the links are not isotopic, there is an orientation-preserving homeomorphism between their exteriors.   The moves that have to do with 1/n surgeries on unknots let you go from one to the other (with the surgery being done on either component).